# Laravel 5.7 cannot change input class using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want user after he enter invoice number and press Enter system check in database if this input value already exists or not using ajax and if the value exist it must change the input class

here is my blade code :

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-form-label" for="inputWarning"><i class="far fa-bell"></i> Input with
                                    warning</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control is-warning" id="invoice_number" name="invoice_number" placeholder="Enter ...">
                            </div>
```

and here is my Ajax code :

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#invoice_number").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var inv_no = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: "{{url('checkInvoice')}}",
                data: {// change data to this object
                    _token : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                    invoice_number:inv_no
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(res) {
                    if(res.exists){
                        alert('true');
                        $(this).removeClass('form-control is-warning').addClass('form-control is-valid');
                    }else{
                        alert('false');
                        $(this).removeClass('form-control is-warning').addClass('form-control is-invalid');

                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

                }
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: How specifically does the code fail?  Are there any errors on the browser's debugging console?  (Do you know how to find the browser's debugging tools?)  In the debugging tools network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: no there is no error and nothing happened the input appearance doesn't change only the alert action fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `success` callback (or in any callback), `this` doesn't mean what you think it means.  The callback happens at a later time and in a later context, so it's no longer referring to the element which triggered the event.

Capture a reference to that element into a variable before making the AJAX request:

```
let self = this;
$.ajax({
  //...
});
```

Then inside of the `success` callback use that variable instead of `this`:

```
$(self).removeClass('form-control is-warning').addClass('form-control is-valid');
```

Comment: How can i thank you now it is working and i understand how to use 'this'

thank you very much MR David